# Cannot push or create a Postgres SQL db to GitLab no matter what I do. Is there a helpful YouTube video or doc? Or need a paid GitLab subscription?

Tags: gitlab

I have spent quite a bit of time on this issue.  Pretty new to GitLab.  Was able to publish my python program and run a pipeline just fine.  But no luck with creating / pushing postgres SQL to GitLab.  There is quite a bit of technical doc on this subject with the GitLab site.  But for someone who has never done this before it is unclear as to what the exact steps are.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Run migration scripts or ? -- In general, it's against the community guidelines to ask for resource recommendations in questions. but if you have a specific problem, we can try to help. Also Welcome to SO :-)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.